# Button Overloading Issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks

Earlier on, I was calling my `addFriend`function (which runs a graphql mutation) from within another function `getFriendId`. It worked perfectly.

```
 const getFriendId = React.useCallback(
    (data: UsersLazyQueryHookResult) => {
      if (data) {
        if (data.users.nodes.length == 0) {
          Alert.alert('User Not Found');
        } else {
          setUserData(data);
          setNumberOfUsers(data.users.nodes.length);
          //showUsers(data, Number(numberOfUsers));
          //addFriend(Number(data.users.nodes[0].id));
        }
      }
    },
    [addFriend],
  );
```

However, now I call it from within my ShowUsers function which first displays all returned users and shows a button with each of them. I am trying this:

```
const showUsers = React.useCallback(
     (data: UsersLazyQueryHookResult, numberOfUsers: Number) => {
       for (var i = 0; i < numberOfUsers; i++) {
         const userId = data.users.nodes[i].id;
         const userName = data.users.nodes[i].firstName
           .concat(' ')
           .concat(data.users.nodes[i].lastName);
         return (
           <View >
             <View >
               <Text >{userName}</Text>
               <Button  
               onPress={addFriend(Number(data.users.nodes[0].id))}
               >
               </Button>
             </View>
           </View>
         );
       }
     },
     [createUserRelationMutation],
   );
```

However, I get an issue on the button's onPress that:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Readonly<Button>): Button', gave the following error.
    Type 'void' is not assignable to type '(() => void) | undefined'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: Button, context?: any): Button', gave the following error.
    Type 'void' is not assignable to type '(() => void) | undefined'.ts(2769)
```

This is my addFriend function:

```
  const addFriend = React.useCallback(
    (id: Number) => {
      createUserRelationMutation({
        variables: {
          input: { relatedUserId: id, type: RelationType.Friend, userId: 7 },
        },
      });
    },
    [createUserRelationMutation],
  );
```

And this is how I use `showUsers`in my main return jsx

```
 {showUsers(userData, Number(numberOfUsers))}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onPress={addFriend(Number(data.users.nodes[0].id))}` this will invoke the `addFriend` function without `onPress` :

So change :

```
onPress={addFriend(Number(data.users.nodes[0].id))}
```

To :

```
onPress={() => addFriend(Number(data.users.nodes[0].id))}
```